# What does the word "Symbol" in Visual Studio mean?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, jetbrains-ide

Visua Studio includes the word "Symbol" multiple times as in "Go to Symbol" or "Usages of symbol". Can I get an explanation for this word and its function in IDEs in general?

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ IDEA a symbol refers to any code element such as method, class, field, etc.